# How to get refresh token in Identity Server 4 with password grant type

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, dotnetopenauth, duende-identity-server

I have a Blazor SPA and a registered client in Identity Server 4 .

I take username and password from user a create an access token request to my identity server 4.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "...",
            ClientId = "360.WASM",
            ClientSecret = "...",
            Scope = "BulutTakin.Appraisal360.WASM",
            GrantType="password",
            UserName = username,
            Password = password,

        });
```

everything is just fine and I get access token as expected but RefreshToken is null.

I want to implement RefreshToken feature in my app and for now I want to get a refresh token when I request an access token.

I was wondering why refresh token is null in my response.

I read the IS4 documentation and it says:

> Refresh tokens are supported for the following flows: authorization code, hybrid and resource owner password credential flow. The clients needs to be explicitly authorized to request refresh tokens by setting AllowOfflineAccess to true

I have set Allow Offline Access to true in my Identity Server 4 Admin Dashboard as well.

this is the response I get:

[image]

[image]

And this is my client configuration:

[image]

any help on getting this done is appreciated.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to add `offline_access` scope to our scope parameter.

```
var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "...",
        ClientId = "360.WASM",
        ClientSecret = "...",
        Scope = "BulutTakin.Appraisal360.WASM offline_access",
        GrantType="password",
        UserName = username,
        Password = password,

    });
```